# Getting Bootstrap Glyphicons to work with Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm trying to load up bootstrap using webpack. The css works just fine, but the glyphicons seem to break by showing a square (see below). No console errors

[image]

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./public/app/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/dist/',
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader" 
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style!css!less"
            },
            { 
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            { 
                test: /\.(ttf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(eot)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
                loader: "file" 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
                loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" 
            },

        ]
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

```html
<i class="done-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /\.png$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
  },
  {
    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
  },
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?|(jpg|gif)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
  }
]
```

and your javascript (assuming npm and modules):

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
```

Just a heads up that webpack is going to put the font files in the same directory as your `bundle.js` file so you may need to ensure that your `index.html` file is also copied to your `dist` folder so the path references are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Possible typo: `minetype` should be `mimetype` for your `woff` file test.

Also mimetype is inferred from the extension I'm not sure you need to provide it.

My only guess (without knowing anything about Twitter bootstrap and if the typo does not solve it) is that your regexes might not be matching so try something like:

`/\.(svg|woff|ttf|eot)(\?v=.*)?$/i`

Which I think is probably a more forgiving test and allows you to use one test instead of many.